# Relación Opcional EFCore 3.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core

Trabajo con `EFCore 3.1`, tengo la necesidad de implementar una relación `Opcional` he hecho lo siguiente:

```
builder.HasOne(c => c.ComprobantePago)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ComprobantePagoId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Según lo que he leído `?` es suficiente

```
public int? ComprobantePagoId { get; set; }
```

No estoy tolalmente convencido, también he visto que le ponen `IsRequired(false)` ¿me pueden indicar si esta bien implementado?

Saludos!

Comment: declarar una variable con ? significa que puede ser null, si haces c?.ComprobantePagoId es para que no rompa, si lo que esta seguid de "c" es null no intentan tomar ese valor o ejecutar dicho metodo entonces no rompe. Ejemplo: si c.ToString(), si "c" es null no intenta hacer el Tostring() y no rompe

Comment: @RamiroBarone ¿entonces esta bien la implementación?

Comment: nunca lo hice de esa manera, te rompe si le pasas null? porque el ? es para tu objeto, la consulta te funciona bien?

Comment: @RamiroBarone Lo debo estar probando mañana hoy estoy terminando la migración. Mañana te comento como me fue.